# How do I perform explain in current mongodb c# driver version?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm just starting with MongoDb driver and I've found multiple posts on Stackoverflow, that say just add `.Explain()` to your IQueryable and it will do the magic. Problem is, that my IDE does not suggest such method.

I've started digging and I see in master branch of MongoDb driver, that Explain extension method is in LinqExtensionMethods class, which itself is in MongoDB.Driver.Legacy, which is not referenced from the current driver?

So what is the approach with current driver?

Comment: It's [ExplainOperation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Core_Operations_ExplainOperation__ctor.htm) in the new core driver. Out of curiosity, what magic do you expect?

Comment: Probably magic was too strong word, I just wish execution plan, that's all. Any idea how to use that ExplainOperation with Linq API, may be example or article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this is by hacking around everything being internal or private inside the MongoDB Driver which I wouldn't advise you doing, however, it's possible with the below code.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Event>("events");

var filter = Builders<Event>.Filter.Gte(x => x.At, DateTime.UtcNow);
var fields = Builders<Event>.Projection.Include(x => x.Name);

var settingsSerializerRegistry = collection.Settings.SerializerRegistry;
var bsonSerializer = settingsSerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<Event>();
var command = new BsonDocument
{
    { "find", collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName },
    { "filter", filter.Render(bsonSerializer, settingsSerializerRegistry)},
    { "projection", fields.Render(bsonSerializer, settingsSerializerRegistry) },
    { "skip", 5 },
    { "limit", 10 },
};

var subject = new ExplainOperation(database.DatabaseNamespace, command, new MessageEncoderSettings())
{
    Verbosity = ExplainVerbosity.QueryPlanner
};
var readPreferenceBinding = new ReadPreferenceBinding(client.Cluster, ReadPreference.Primary, NoCoreSession.NewHandle());

var explain = subject.Execute(readPreferenceBinding, CancellationToken.None);
//{ "queryPlanner" : { "plannerVersion" : 1, "namespace" : "test.events", "indexFilterSet" : false, "parsedQuery" : { "At" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2020-03-14T23:45:37.143Z") } }, "winningPlan" : { "stage" : "EOF" }, "rejectedPlans" : [] }, "serverInfo" : { "host" : "DESKTOP-ULTR09L", "port" : 27017, "version" : "4.2.3", "gitVersion" : "6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4" }, "ok" : 1.0 }
```

However, the explain extensions are in the [MongoDB.Driver.Legacy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver) package, this still is supported for anything that can run .NETStandard 1.5 and .NETFramework 4.5.2

So this might be a better route for you!

You can install it from the package manager

```
Install-Package mongocsharpdriver
```

Then you can use the following extensions to call explain on a query:

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();

var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Event>("events");
var explain = collection.AsQueryable()
    .Where(c => c.At >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1) && c.At < DateTime.UtcNow)
    .Take(1)
    .Explain();
```

It's a lot more simpler.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas why they dropped it from LINQ in current version, are they planning to bring it back? Or in general c# community for mongodb thinks that LINQ implementation is not very successful and it is not used much in production?

Comment: From experience, the LINQ implementations are used a lot (and write efficient queries too), however, when optimizing queries I've enabled profiling in MongoDB instead of trying to do it from the actual application. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/

Comment: This does not work for me, the `BsonDocument` class doesn't implement the `IExplainableOperation` interface which is the type expected by the `ExplainOperation` ctor...